# why does my array of strings assignment not work with pointers?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, dereference

I have a struct that stores 5 `char *` pointers

```
struct x {

       char *arr[5];
};
```

I allocated memory for the struct using malloc()

`struct x *str = malloc(sizeof(struct x));`

However when i try to initialize `arr` with a value (namely a read only string-literal) it gives me an error

```
error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
   13 |     (*str).(*(arr+0)) = "hello";
                   ^
```

here is my initialization

```
(*str).(*(arr+0)) = "hello";
```

i know i could do it like this

`str->arr[0] = "hello"`

but i would like to understand how array of strings work, so i have used pointers and firstly dereferenced `str->` and changed it to `(*str)`.

Also since `arr[0]` works in the initialization `str->arr[0] = "hello"` and i know that `arr[0]` is equivalent to `*(arr+i)` where `i` is a array cell, i though that this would work in  `(*str).(*(arr+0)) = "hello";` but it does not.

Why is this and how are arrays of strings actually working behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure has the data member arr.

```
struct x {

       char *arr[5];
};
```

So you have to write accessing the data member using the operator `.` or `->` for example like

```
*( (*str).arr + 0) = "hello";
```

that is the same as

```
*(*str).arr = "hello";
```

or

```
*str->arr = "hello";
```

Or

```
str->arr[0] = "hello";
```

That is member access operators are defined like

```
postfix-expression . identifier 
postfix-expression -> identifier
```

while you are trying to use an expression that is not an identifier.

Using your approach to access ant element of the array you can write

```
*( (*str).arr + i) = "hello";
```

or

```
*( str->arr + i) = "hello";
```

That is at first you need to get the array designator like

```
( *str ).arr
```

or

```
str->arr
```

and then  you can use the pointer arithmetic with the obtained array.

Comment: in ```*( (*str).arr + i) = "hello";``` why do you dereference the whole thing? as far as i understand you access the struct with ```(*str)``` then you use ```.arr+i``` to access the ith element of the array. so why dereference the whole thing?

Comment: @programme3219873: The *expression* `(*str).arr + i` has type `char *[5]`, which "decays" to `char **`; the expression `"hello"` has type `char [6]`, which "decays" to `char *`.  `char **` is not the same as `char *`, so we need to dereference `(*str).arr + i` for the types to match.  And for everyone's sanity, use the `->` and `[]` operators - `str->arr[i]` is much easier to read and understand than `*((*str).arr + i)`

Comment: @programme3219873 You have an array of pointers. So the expression ( *str ).arr + i points to the i-th element of the array and has the type char **. To get the pointed element you need to dereference the pointer expression like *( (*str ).arr + i ).

Comment: @JohnBode ( *str ).arr + i has the type char **.